Communicating between two subnets
I have the following network configuration:

ISP Modem Router Huwawei EG8145V5
[LAN IP 192.168.1.1/24] with its LAN port connected to the WAN port of a...

Xiaomi AX3000
[WAN IP (from ISP Modem Router) 192.168.1.2/24
and LAN IP 192.168.31.1/24]


An NVR is connected to the Xiaomi AX3000, with LAN IP 192.168.31.10/24, and multiple IP cameras downstream.
When connected to the Xiaomi AX 3000 [IP 192.168.31.x/24], I can access the NVR and the ISP Modem Router without problems.  But when I connect to the ISP Modem Router [IP 192.168.1.x/24], I can no longer access the NVR locally.
I tried setting a static route in the ISP Modem Router as follows:
IP Address 192.168.31.0/24 ; Gateway 192.168.1.2 ; br0 to no avail.  Is it possible for a PC connected to the ISP Modem Router to access the NVR?

In a home setting it is often an overcomplication to have more than one router. Unless you have some specific need. Using your Xiaomi router as a simple network switch (or access point) might do all you need.

The route is correct, but because the Xiaomi expects to be hooked up directly to Internet, it very likely also has a firewall that blocks all connections coming from the WAN interface. (It can't automatically know where the boundary truly is, so it always sticks to the safest option.)
You'll need to adjust its firewall rules to allow connections from 192.168.1.x/24.
(If the router doesn't let you configure its firewall separately, you might have to use the "port forwarding" method instead.)

Thank you for this! What is the port forwarding method? The xiaomi does not let me configure its firewall settings.

It would literally be configuring a "port forward" or "virtual server" rule on the Xiaomi like if you were opening up a port for public access (i.e. the same thing people do for game servers etc), and then your PC would have to connect to the router's IP (192.168.1.2 in this case) instead of being able to specify the true NVR IP.

Will fiddle with this later. Thank you!
